# WordPress: forcefully generate pagination url for 1st page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to generate pagination URL for first page. I used the following code.

```
get_pagenum_link(1); // gives http://www.website.com/
```

anyhow,

```
get_pagenum_link(2); // gives http://www.website.com/paged/2/
```

`get_pagenum_link` checks for the page # `if($paged == 1) {// Don't include Page# in URL }` I want to disable this check so that, it always include page #in URL

Also, http://www.website.com/paged/1/ is redirected to http://www.website.com/ I added a filter

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');
function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
    return false;
}
```

but, I think, its not a right way to do, it'll stop all canonical redirections.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this function into theme’s functions.php**

```
function custom_pagination() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Usage :

**To call this function you have to add the below php code in your theme’s index.php, archive.php, category.php, or any other page template.**

```
<?php custom_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: I just need the url for a given Page number. not the whole pagination.